# remove intervals between timestamp in R

Tags: r, datetime

I want to remove intervals in my df which are not on the hour or an hour apart from the previous row.

For example:

```
timestamp
2021-03-01 12:00
2021-03-01 12:10
2021-03-01 12:20
2021-03-01 12:30
2021-03-01 12:40
2021-03-01 13:00
2021-03-01 14:30
2021-03-01 15:30
2021-03-01 16:30
2021-03-02 12:00
2021-03-02 12:10
2021-03-02 12:20
2021-03-02 12:30
2021-03-02 12:40
2021-03-02 13:00
2021-03-03 11:00
2021-03-03 11:10
2021-03-03 11:20
2021-03-03 11:30
2021-03-03 11:40
2021-03-03 12:00
2021-03-03 13:10
2021-03-03 14:10
2021-03-03 15:10
```

The df as many dates and the intervals can occur between any hour, and not all intervals are 10 mins.

What I would like to end up with is:

timestamp

```
2021-03-01 12:00
2021-03-01 13:00
2021-03-01 14:30
2021-03-01 15:30
2021-03-01 16:30
2021-03-02 12:00
2021-03-02 13:00
2021-03-03 11:00
2021-03-03 12:00
2021-03-03 13:10
2021-03-03 14:10
2021-03-03 15:10
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `round_date()` from `lubridate`.

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(id = 1:4,
                 timestamp = ymd_hm(
                   c(
                     "2021-03-01 12:10",
                     "2021-03-01 12:00",
                     "2021-03-01 13:30",
                     "2021-03-01 14:00"
                   )
                 ))

precise <- round_date(df$timestamp, unit = "hour")

df |> dplyr::filter(timestamp %in% precise)
```

(PS: these are date-times, not intervals).

Comment: thank you - but in my example it has instances where there is 12:30, 13:30 as well as round times (12:00, 13:00). But removing any which are 10 minutes apart would work?

Comment: You edited your requirements after asking the question. At the moment your intended output does not match your requirements: 14:30 is not an hour apart from 13:00.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, also using `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

timestamp <- c("2021-03-01 12:00", "2021-03-01 12:10", "2021-03-01 12:20", "2021-03-01 12:30",
               "2021-03-01 12:40", "2021-03-01 13:00", "2021-03-01 14:30", "2021-03-01 15:30",
               "2021-03-01 16:30", "2021-03-02 12:00", "2021-03-02 12:10", "2021-03-02 12:20",
               "2021-03-02 12:30", "2021-03-02 12:40", "2021-03-02 13:00", "2021-03-03 11:00",
               "2021-03-03 11:10", "2021-03-03 11:20", "2021-03-03 11:30", "2021-03-03 11:40",
               "2021-03-03 12:00", "2021-03-03 13:10", "2021-03-03 14:10", "2021-03-03 15:10")

data <- data.frame(timestamp)

timestamp_exit <- data %>% 
  mutate(timestamp = format(as.POSIXct(timestamp), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')) %>% 
  filter(minute(timestamp) == 0)
```

Output

```
> timestamp_exit
         timestamp
1 2021-03-01 12:00
2 2021-03-01 13:00
3 2021-03-02 12:00
4 2021-03-02 13:00
5 2021-03-03 11:00
6 2021-03-03 12:00
```

---

As for the time intervals: This is a little function that rolls along your `timestamp` column and finds each consecutive timestamp being at least one hour apart. Note however, that there is no rounding up the minutes here, but it matches your desired output.

```
hourinterval <- function(interval, ind = 1) {
  ind.next <- first(which(difftime(interval, interval[ind], units="hours") >= 1))
if(is.na(ind.next))
    return(ind)
  else
    return(c(ind, hourinterval(interval, ind.next)))
}

timestamp_exit2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(timestamp = format(as.POSIXct(timestamp), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')) %>%
  slice(hourinterval(timestamp))
```

Output

```
> timestamp_exit2
          timestamp
1  2021-03-01 12:00
2  2021-03-01 13:00
3  2021-03-01 14:30
4  2021-03-01 15:30
5  2021-03-01 16:30
6  2021-03-02 12:00
7  2021-03-02 13:00
8  2021-03-03 11:00
9  2021-03-03 12:00
10 2021-03-03 13:10
11 2021-03-03 14:10
12 2021-03-03 15:10
```